# Streaming media using flash with a cross-domain proxy

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, apache, same-origin-policy

Lets say I have a PHP application using very cheap shared hosting.   What is the best way to stream audio/video (mp3/mpeg) that is tens of megabytes to hundreds of megabytes in size.  I am thinking of a PHP based cross-domain proxy that uses caching.  Is there something wrong with this approach?  Has someone already done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Amazon Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) - it's a CDN that offers streaming using Flash Media Server. I recently setup a project using it and it was pretty easy to get up and running (I had no prior CDN or streaming experience). Of course, you'll have to see if the cost compares to your existing setup. I think by using a CDN you completely sidestep the issue of needing a cross-domain proxy.

Comment: +1 Content Delivery Networks are a very good alternative to hosting it yourself. Usually you on pay for bandwidth. As for the crossdomain issue you will still need the service to have one with allowing access from your site.